# How can I resolve this error and install vue.js in docker

Tags: docker, vue.js

I'm trying to install vue.js in docker. However it comes with an error and I am completely stuck at this point. Please help me solving this issue.

I've already prepared DockerFile and docker-compose.yml.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: vue-curriculum
    ports:
      - '8880:8880'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    tty: true
```

`Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM node:15.11.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Process:

```bash
docker-compose up -d # could make a container 
docker container exec -it [container name] sh 
vue create .
```

Here comes an error...

```
Vue CLI v5.0.8
? Generate project in current directory? Yes


Vue CLI v5.0.8
? Please pick a preset: Default ([Vue 2] babel, eslint)
? Pick the package manager to use when installing dependencies: Yarn


Vue CLI v5.0.8
✨  Creating project in /app.
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

yarn install v1.22.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error jest-worker@28.1.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0". Got "15.11.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
 ERROR  Error: command failed: yarn 
Error: command failed: yarn 
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/executeCommand.js:138:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
/app #
```

Comment: Why don't you run the `vue create` in the `Dockerfile`? Do you need to attach to the container to do this?

Comment: The workflow you're describing seems backwards: you're building a reproducible image, then connecting to it with a debugger, then trying to bootstrap the application in it.  Can you do this in the opposite order, run `vue create` on the host with a plain non-Docker Node installation, develop and debug it, and then package it into a reproducible image for deployment?